# LTspice error: No AC stimulus found

Tags: ltspice, spice

I am using LTspice to simulate the AC analysis of a circuit. When I open the netlist of the circuit in LTspice and run the simulation, I get the following error:

[image: LTspice error]

An example of the netlist that I'm using is:

[image]

I have placed an independent current source between nodes 5 and 1 in the first line of the netlist: `I1 5 1 AC 1`. I want to know why am I getting this error and how to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first line in a netlist must be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If your "netlist" is meant to be a *subcircuit*, then the first line needs to be

`.subckt <subcircuit_name> [pins] <optional_parameters>`

Don't forget about the `.ends` ending line (note, `.ends`, **not** `.end` -- this means the end of the whole netlist; anything afterwards will be ignored).

If it's meant to be a generic circuit, the first line should be a comment, which means `*`, `;`, or `#` at the beginning.